# On Byobu, how to refer to the directory of another split?

Tags: byobu

I love Byobu and hate the Midnight Commander (MC), especially because MC collides with Byobu's keybindings. But quite often I split a Byobu window vertically and wished I could simply copy a file from one split to the other as I can do with MC. Something like this:

```
cp file.txt $b1
```

Where $b1 would be a variable pointing to the location where the split 1 currently is. I could try adding some trick to each shell (for instance, using an alias for the cd command, saving the current location to a file, reading it somehow on another shell), but invariably a shell session would need to find its own split number. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can have more than one window on the same session, so I think that's unlikely to be possible.

E.g. what should happen here? :

[image: 4way terminal split]

Comment: In this case I would want to refer to splits using something like `$b1_0`, `$b1_1`, ..., `$b1_n`.

Comment: @Akira I don't know what to say. I don't think byobu can do variable changing inside the running shells, when it moves its buffers around.

Comment: I know. It's just that the byobu maintainer monitors the byobu tag, so I was hoping to get his attention. :D